# How to assist my manager with post covid recovery symptoms when meeting with vendors

Tags: united-states, manager, meetings, covid-19

I work in a management role in the cybersecurity division of my company.

My manager recently caught Covid and is still recovering. While his physical symptoms are almost all gone, there is some "mental fog" remaining. This was told to me by himself and he seemed apologetic. Today in a 1:1, this was apparent via:

- Slowed responses to questions
- More requests to repeat what was just said than usual
- Losing train of thought in middle of sentences
- Reduced ability to find the next words
- increased fatigue in appearance

To make matters worse, we needed vendor technical support for a product my division is using, and during the conference call with video present, same symptoms as above were present. The high pressure environment certainly did not help nor the unfamiliar audience present.

> Should I have done anything to help my manager out?

> How do I help out without giving offense or embarrassing my manager in such video conference call?

Comment: Have you talked to your manager about this and asked him these questions?

Comment: Why would a manager and his manager be the people to go to a meeting with vendors? This does not make any sense. Managers should manage. There is no reason for them to interact with vendors.

Comment: @stevev The manager already has mental fog. What's good to ask them these questions  ?

Comment: @Gantendo - if there are issues getting the necessary support from a vendor, it's appropriate and sometimes very necessary to get a manager or two involved. It's also appropriate if there have been changes to the support agreement(s) with an existing vendor, and when onboarding a new vendor.

Comment: @Nobody: Being foggy does not mean being completely out of it. Slower response, some specific deficits possibly -- but this is still something where you ask them in advance what would be helpful, and give them the time needed, rather than stepping on their toes without warning or coordination.

Comment: What kind of timeframe are we talking about? Did the manager have covid three days ago, or three months ago?

Comment: @Stef, 2 weeks ago

Comment: If on Zoom or Meet, turning on closed captioning or wearing a headset could be helpful as well. Hearing loss is a potential symptom of Covid for some folks.

Comment: @keshlam exactly. I'm currently unfortunately in exactly the same situation my infection has been 3 weeks ago but I'm nowhere able to do my old workload and I'm having major problems with concentration. Which means you have to prioritize, so just ask him what he can handle and how you can be of help and work with what you got. Just try to be understanding.

Answer (score 4):

I often have group meetings where people on my side are not particularly good at English or have incomplete understanding, bad communication skills, or some other issue that makes them sub-optimal representatives of our team.

If I have a vested interest in the subject or I'm responsible for a successful outcome then I just take control of our side of the meeting. If not, then I don't care, I just concentrate on my portion.

This might be a solution for you as well.

Answer (score 3):

So, these suggestions are predicated on the following:

1: The Manager in question acknowledges they are struggling.
2: They've asked for assistance.

Here are some 'tactics' that you can use to try and limit the damage:

- Chance favors the prepared mind.

Now, normally with any meeting, there will be some form of Prep work done - it could be reviewing the SoW from the customer, checking the status of JIRA, checking emails etc. either way, the first step is to be over-prepared. The less 'thinking' in the middle of the meeting that your manager has to do, and the more 'wrote repetition' they can do (because you've already prepared the possible questions from the client) the easier it should be for them.

- There's no shame in Action items.

If your manager is getting mental fog and going off on tangents - you may want to have a system in place whereby you signal to your manager to cut it short and take an action item - could be something like sending an emoji directly in Teams (for example) - Whilst it could be frustrating for the client to have a larger than normal number of action items - so long as you get these covered off within a prompt time-frame (say EoB or the next business day) - if the client queries this - you can always say that you need to confirm a couple of details with someone not in the meeting.

- Get your manager to defer authority.

I'm very comfortable driving meetings. Case in point, I recently transferred to a new job - so I'm very much the FNG - at our daily standup, our manager was AFK - and after the other team members started looking all around, I jumped in to drive the meeting - after 5-10 minutes the manager arrived (unexpected customer call) and they just sat back and let me finish driving the meeting. At the start of the meeting you can say that you will be chairing the meeting as *insert excuse as to why your manager would be taking a secondary role* and then when there are questions that only your manager can answer - take an action item etc.

- Camera off.

I'm not going to wade into the whole politics of Camera on/Camera off. I myself am almost always camera on - but that's for me, I don't care if someone is Camera off - whatever makes them comfortable. However, there are times when Camera Off is 'understandable' e.g. 'I'm not in a private area and am unable to turn my camera on' - this directly deals with the appearance of looking fatigued.

Those are the best I got.

However - there is one other alternative:

**Be upfront with the client**

"Just so you know - Bob is joining this meeting specifically, but Bob isn't 100% at the moment, so please bear that in mind"

That way, any perceived fogginess can be attributed to the Bob not being 100%.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer to "how can I help someone" is "ask them whether they would like help, and if so what kind."

This is sometimes shorthanded as "maintain agency."

Answer (score 0):

Your manager is an adult, so giving them as much respect and agency as possible is key. It might even be worth not referencing their mental fog in offering help - i.e. "These upcoming meetings are pretty important right? Let me know if there's anything I can do for you to make sure they go well. I am also happy to jump in and assist if you want me to get more practice in a speaking role in these meetings."

There are also some things you can do if you don't feel comfortable asking, such as taking notes on the meeting or preparing slides/materials for the meeting ahead of time.